# How to know an activity that loses focus will enter paused state, but won't enter stopped state in onPause callback

Tags: android

Is there any API through which we can get that an Activity will only enter paused state and won't enter Stopped state in `onPause` callback.

Comment: No you can't know that. An `Activity` may be stopped for whatever reason at any point in time after it is paused. It's unknowable beforehand. However there is a getter which tells you if `finish()` has been called. So you can know if the `Activity` will quit, but that doesn't apply to the `Activity` just being in the background.

Comment: I see, so I need to find a new way to solve my problem. Thanks very much.